# Limit of $\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2x + 5x^2} - e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)} {\sin(x^2)} $ with Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

How to calculate the limit of the following function using Taylor series:

$$\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2x + 5x^2} - e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)}
{\sin(x^2)}
$$

I know how to get the series for $\sin(x^2)$, but do not know, how to get it for the other two functions. Does $\sqrt{1 + 2x + 5x^2}$ have to be at $a=0$, or can it be at $a=1/5$?
And is the only way to get the first few terms of $e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)$ by sticking to the formula for Taylor series ($f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$) or is there an easier way (with less differentiating)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, compute each Taylor expansion independently:

- $\sqrt{1+2x+5x^2}\sim1+x+2x^2$
- $\exp(3x)\sim 1+3x+\frac{9}{2}x^2$
- $\cos(2\sqrt(x))\sim 1-2x+\frac{2}{3}x^2$
- $\sin(x^2)\sim x^2$

Then, calculate the product of the Taylor series up to order 2 for $\exp(3x)\cos(2\sqrt{x})\sim 1+(3-2)x+(9/2-2/3-6)x^2=-\frac{5}{6}x^2$.

Then, compute the expansion of the numerator up to the second order: $\sim (2+\dfrac{5}{6})x^2$. And conclude by calculating the ratio and you find that the limit is $\dfrac{17}{6}$.

**Edit** Here are the details for the Taylor expansion of the square root. I assume you know that $(1+\epsilon)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon - \frac{1}{8}\epsilon^2 + o(\epsilon^2)$ for $\epsilon$ in the neighbourhood of $0$. Here, $2x+5x^2$ is in the neighbourhood of $0$ when $x$ is, so it yields:
\begin{align}(1+(2x+5x^2))^{1/2}&=1+\frac{1}{2}(2x+5x^2)-\frac{1}{8}(2x+5x^2)^2+o(x^2)=1+x+(\frac{5}{2}-\frac{4}{8})x^2+o(x^2)\\ &=1+x+2x^2+o(x^2)
\end{align}

Note that I only considered the terms of order lower or equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found a typo in my question. Under the square root, it is $1+2x+5x^2$. Can you please update your answer so that it includes that.  Very sorry for the inconviniences.

Comment: @Ravonrip Well, if you understood you should be able to correct it :)

Comment: @Ravonrip edited accordingly

Comment: I understood, but do not know, how to get the expansion of that square root. Does it have to be at a=0, or can it be at a=1/5, and than just multiply the first two terms of that series.

Comment: @Ravonrip You should compute each expansion in the neighbourhood of $x=0$ (so $a=0$).

Comment: But how can I do that? I tried adding it to perfect squares, but to no avail.

Comment: @Ravonrip OK, I'll add the details for the square root.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to differentiate: you can make  arithmetic operations on Taylor's approximations, compose them, &c.

- $\sqrt{1+2x+5x^2}=1+\frac12(2x+5x^2)-\frac18(2x+5x^2)^2+o(x^2)=1+x+2x^2+o(x)^2\;$ if $x\ge -1$.
- $\cos(2\sqrt x) =1-2x +\frac23x^2+o(x^2)$ ( for $x\ge0$).
- $\mathrm e^{3x}=1+3x+\frac92x^2+o(x)$, whence
  $$\mathrm e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x) =(1-2x +\tfrac23x^2 +o(x^2))(1+3x+\tfrac92x^2+o(x^2))=1+x-\tfrac56x^2+o(x^2)$$
  Thus 
  $$\sqrt{1+2x+5x^2}-\mathrm e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)= \tfrac{17}6 x^2+o(x^2)\sim_0\tfrac{17}6 x^2,$$
  and finally
  $$\frac{\sqrt{1+2x+5x^2}-\mathrm e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)}{\sin x^2}\sim_0\frac{\tfrac{17}6 x^2}{x^2}=\frac{17}6.$$

Comment: It seems that you missed the $5$ in the first radical. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Oh! yes. I should have checked the starting point. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: There are still a few places where you need to edit.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Yes, thanks. Hope it's OK now :o)

Comment: You didn't miss anything, the 5 was added later :)

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as previous answers, you could even go further using the following reference series built around $y=0$ for $\sqrt{1+y}$,  $e^y$,  $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$ Now,  replace successively $y$ by $ (2x+5x^2)$, by $3x$,   by $2 \sqrt x$ and by $x^2$.

You will then get, limiting to order $4$ $$\sqrt{1+2x+5x^2}=1+x+2 x^2-2 x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$e^{3x}=1+3 x+\frac{9 x^2}{2}+\frac{9 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\cos(2 \sqrt x)=1-2 x+\frac{2 x^2}{3}-\frac{4 x^3}{45}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\sin(x^2)=x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Doing so, the expression becomes 
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2x + 5x^2} - e^{3x}\cos(2\sqrt x)}
{\sin(x^2)}=\frac{\frac{17 x^2}{6}+\frac{53 x^3}{90}+O\left(x^4\right) } {x^2+O\left(x^4\right) }=\frac{17}{6}+\frac{53 }{90}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which show the limit and also how it is approached.